# Slack bot sending messages two times when only one was called

Tags: django, python-3.x, slack-api

Im currently building a simple web page with django that runs some code on the back.

For running certaing methods, I created a slack bot. Let me explain the process

From some channel, a user can type
`@Orchestrator help`

And they will receive a response with the commands the bot has. One of the commands is `start_recon`, so the message looks like this

`@Orchestrator start_recon <some_target>`

This is received by a endpoint called `slack_in`, which looks like this

```
@csrf_exempt
@require_POST
def slack_input(request):
    data = request.body
    data = json.loads(data.decode())
    if 'challenge' in data:
        return JsonResponse({'challenge': data})
    response = slack_receiver.receive_bot_message(data)
    return HttpResponse(status=response)
```

This then get parsed with `receive_bot_message` and from there the different tasks start.

Expected behaviour:

Both `@Orchestrator help` and `@Orchestrator start_recon <target>` send one request to the `slack_in` endpoint

Actual behaviour

`@Orchestrator start_recon <target>` is sending 2 identical requests but `@Orchestrator help` is sending one.

Comment: I think  your `slack_receiver` is taking more than 3 second to send reponse back to slack, in this case salck will resubmit its payload, thats why your server is sending messages twice.

`https://claudiajs.com/tutorials/slack-delayed-responses.html`, here you will get some insights

Comment: I'll try reducing the time and see how it goes, thanks!

Comment: Try using delayed responses or send back an empty success response then handling the bulk of your process after this.